# How to render div as 100% of parent not child

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a scrollable panel within a table cell.

What I would like is for the div to be as wide as the table cell and then render scrollbars for the content.

When I try the following the div sets its width to 100% of the contained span tag not the cell

```
<table cellpadding="3" width="90%" align="center" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="border: solid 1px red; height: 10px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
          <span style="width: 2000px;">a</span>
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was under the impressing that width=100% should size on parent not on child?

Any ideas?

Comment: It has occurred to me that maybe the span is affecting the size of the table cell - does that make sense?

Comment: It would help if we could see the rest of your markup. CSS width has some requirements about parent elements having their width set as well.

Comment: Yes, I think the span is the one that affects the cell width.

Comment: A span element is not even block-level, so whatever browser you are using that is applying a width to it must be technically handicapped!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty table cell has no width, the span is the one that's forcing the width of the cell. That's why the div width is equal to the cell width.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it within a containing div instead of a table and it works fine.

I assume that the inner span width is causing the td width to be 2000px